# java Diagonal 2d array copy

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am trying to make a method that copies the elements in an array diagonally.

```
{{0,0,0,0,9},
 {0,0,0,8,0},
 {0,0,7,0,0},
 {0,6,0,0,0}, 
 {5,0,0,0,0}}
```

becomes

```
{{9,0,0,0,9},
 {0,8,0,8,0},
 {0,0,7,0,0},
 {0,6,0,6,0},
 {5,0,0,0,5}}
```

I tried:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
        a[i][j] = a[a.length-1][j];
    }
}
```

but that doesn't seem to work.  Can anyone help me out with what is wrong with my code?  Thanks.

Comment: You want 0s to be overwritten?

Comment: yeah... just trying to copy the diagonal.

Comment: Copy one diagonal elements to another diagonal, right?

Comment: @vidit: that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify how it's "not working", but it looks like the problem is that you only want the old value to be overwritten for nonzero values.

If so, all you need to do is add an extra check. You also have a problem with the indexing where you are always taking the last column. You need to subtract `i` from the index on the righthand side.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
    {
        int temp = a[a.length-i-1][j];
        if (temp != 0) {a[i][j] = a[a.length-i-1][j];}
    }
}
```

Edit: If all you want to do is copy the opposite diagonal onto the main diagonal, it's much simpler.

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    a[i][i] = a[a.length-1-i][i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks the second one did it.  I can't believe it was that simple.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
        {
            if (i==j)
            a[i][j] = a[i][a[i].length-1-j];
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you did.